# Listview duplicates item every 6 times

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, duplicates, listview-adapter

Hope everyone's good;

I know this issue was reviewed earlier couple of times but after a long search I still didn't find a solution.

My custom listview duplicates items every 6 item.

**Already checked and tried:**

**1-** layout_width and layout_height doesn't contain wrap_content

**2-** holder = new ListViewItem() is before any initialization of contents

**3-** There is a "convertView != null"

**4-** holder.linearLayout.getChild() can't be use in my case because the layout isn't   Linear

**5-** clear()

If anyone can help me this is my codes

getView() of CustomListViewAdapter.java

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);
    ListViewItem holder;


    View vi=convertView;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)    getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    if(vi==null){

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ListViewItem();
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.Item1);
        holder.sp = (Spinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.Item2);
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Item3);
        holder.pricetitle= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item4);
        holder.Descriptiontitle= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Item5);
        vi.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ListViewItem) vi.getTag();
    }



    holder.title.setText(item.ItemTitle);
    holder.pricetitle.setText(item.price+"");
    holder.Descriptiontitle.setText(item.Description);

    return vi;  
}
```

ListViewItem class

```
static class ListViewItem{
    public String ItemTitle;
    public int price;
    public String Description;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView pricetitle;
    public TextView Descriptiontitle;
    public CheckBox cb;
    public Spinner sp;
}
```

MainActivity

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.starterbottom, null);

    ListView myList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.MyListStarter);

    List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        items.add(new ListViewItem(){{
            ItemTitle = "Starter Title";
            Description= "Your description goes here";
            price=0;
        }});

    }

    CustomListViewAdapter listadapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

    myList.setAdapter(listadapter);

    return v;
}
```

**EDIT**

MainmenuActivity.java

```
public class MainmenuActivity extends SlidingActivity{


Button buttononside;
TextView title;
FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
PageIndicator mIndicator;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.sidemenu);

    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    mIndicator = (PageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(200);
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree(0.35f);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
    title.setText("Starters");




}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    getSlidingMenu().toggle();

}

public void changecolor(View v){
    buttononside = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());


    buttononside.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                buttononside.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); 
            else
                buttononside.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshape);
            return true;
        }

    });
}


static class ListViewItem{
    public String ItemTitle;
    public int price;
    public String Description;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView pricetitle;
    public TextView Descriptiontitle;
    public CheckBox cb;
    public Spinner sp;
}

}
```

FragmentAdapter.java

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter{

  public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) 
{
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new StarterActivity();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new MainActivity();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SecondActivity();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ThirdActivity();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new FourthActivity();
        break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    String title = "";
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        title = "First";
        break;
    case 1:
        title = "Second";
        break;
    case 2:
        title = "Third";
        break;
    case 3:
        title = "Fourth";
        break;
    }
    return title;
 }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {


int i=0;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.starterbottom, null);

    ListView myList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.MyListStarter);

    List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){

        items.add(new ListViewItem(){{
            ItemTitle = "Title "+i;
            Description= i+" Your Own description";
            price= i;
        }});

    }

    CustomListViewAdapter listadapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, items);

    myList.setAdapter(listadapter);

    return v;

    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Chris

Comment: `Listview duplicates item every 6 times` - What does this mean? In the `for-loop` inside your `onCreateView()`, change `price=0;` to `price=i;`. Do the items still duplicate?

Comment: Seems like there is stuff missing from your code that makes it hard to diagnose the issue.  From what you have included, there is nothing blatantly obvious.  I would try changing `ListViewItem item = items.get(position);` to `ListViewItem item = getItem(position)` assuming that you mistakenly put `CustomListView.java` instead of `CustomListViewAdapter.java`

Comment: And why is the layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in your adapter's constructor? You are inflating, changing, and returning a custom one in your getView().

Comment: The only issue i see in the getView, is that you forgot to "reset" the values of some of the childs in the holder, which would cause that for example: if one element DOES HAVE price properly display it, but if another element DO NOT have price, that text will be filled with one of the reused views...

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick replies I really apperciate that..

@vikram if i set price=i; I get the correct order from 0 to 9.. but if I checked the CheckBox on position 0 it will get checked automatically on position 6 too..
I didn't catch the simple_list_item_1 , i did change it to R.layout.item correctly but it didn't fix my problem yet.

Comment: @Chris yes sorry it's CustomListViewAdapter.java .. already tried to manipulate getItem(position) but without success.. thanks anws

Comment: @Martin thanks for pointing this out for me but till now i'm just trying out the app.. later on i will link it and get the prices from a database so i wont have this problem anymore.

Comment: Chris, can you post the code when you define the behavior for `CheckBox`? Better yet, post the whole of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Well it's kind of complicated because i'm using slidingmenu, viewpagerindicator and fragmentadapter too.. I will edit and post the mainmenuactivity which loads the slidingmenu and the fragmentadapter that sets the fragments of the ViewPagerIndicator :)

Comment: If clicking on the one `CheckBox` is affecting two of them, then it would be helpful to post code where you set them up, set their `OnClickListeners` etc.

Comment: @vikram ummm i didn't implement any OnClickListener yet..but the problem is also present with the Spinner.. so I don't think it's a listener problem..

Comment: @vikram I tried adding  holder.cb.setChecked(false); to the getView()... the postion 6 isn't getting checked anymore but when scrolling position 0 also gets unchecked.. I guess using savedInstanceState will solve my problem? any ideas?

Comment: I'll explain the problem. But, can try the code in my post below? If it works, we can discuss on this issue.

Comment: If you are using extends BaseAdapter then this solution will work.
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/28791031/4531507](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28791031/4531507)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the problem now. And no, there is no duplication here. Carry out these few changes:

In your static class `ListViewItem`, add `boolean isChecked;`

```
static class ListViewItem{
    public String ItemTitle;
    public int price;
    public String Description;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView pricetitle;
    public TextView Descriptiontitle;
    public CheckBox cb;
    public Spinner sp;
    public boolean isChecked;    // <--- added
}
```

Change the initialization of `items`:

```
items.add(new ListViewItem(){{
        ItemTitle = "Starter Title";
        Description= "Your description goes here";
        price=i;
        isChecked = false;
    }});
```

In the getView() method, after `holder.Descriptiontitle.setText(item.Description);`, add:

```
holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                item.isChecked = true;
    } else {
                item.isChecked = false;
            } 
  }
});


if (item.isChecked) {
    holder.cb.setChecked(true);
} else {
    holder.cb.setChecked(false);
}
```

Add the `final` keyword to `ListViewItem item = items.get(position);`:

```
final ListViewItem item = items.get(position);
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @vikram for taking the time to help me out it finally worked :) I'm really grateful !!
I understood that I had to initialize if the checkbox was checked or no.. but why did the listener solve my problem if there isn't anything affecting the other checkboxes?

Comment: I'm having an issue now with the Spinner.. after scrolling the values get messed up.. I'm using the setOnItemSelectedListener if anyone has an idea what might be the problem

Comment: @Chris Use a similar approach(one that you used tosolve the CheckBox problem). Create a integer variable in `ListViewItem` like `int spinnerValue`. Add a ` setOnItemSelectedListener (AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener)` listener to Spinner instances in your getView(). When a values is selected from this spinner the method `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` will be called. Save the `position` to `spinnerValue` of the `ListViewItem`.

Comment: @Chris In your getView(), add a line of code: `holder.sp.setSelection(item.spinnerValue)`. Don't forget to initialize these values in the for-loop in MainActivity: `spinnerValue = 0`.

Comment: man i don't know how to thank you.. I was doing like you mentioned but using setOnItemClickListener instead of setOnItemSelectedListener even though I know that I need to use the first one lol.. Everything works great now.. your the best thanks a lot :)