# Adding headers above ListView in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm trying to add 3 headers going from left to right above a ListView. I'm trying to add TextViews to achieve this. I've attached a picture to better demonstrate. [Picture](https://postimg.org/image/6b8qhgg9r/)

My ListView works as i want it to by itself but I can't seem to get the textViews to align as i want them to.

activity_visualise.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latitudeHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/longitudeHeader"
        android:text="@string/latitudeHeader"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longitudeHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView"
        android:text="@string/longitudeHeader"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/syncHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/longitudeHeader"
        android:text="@string/syncHeader"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_visualise_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_visualise_database"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.softshack.VisualiseDatabaseActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dbLatitude"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dbLongitude"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dbReportTime"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dbSyncStatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't align it properly in XML so I added the headers into the listview as strings. Had issues with them randomly repeating and this fixed it [List view items changes position when scrolling android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790412/list-view-items-changes-position-when-scrolling-android/28791031#28791031)

Comment: check my answer above yoklan. It works. Or you can use the hardcode approach but that kind of depends if you want your app to look nice on all devices or only the one you are working on now

Answer (score 0):

As the parent of your header view use a linear layout (horizontal) and apply a weightSum of 1 on it. then add 4 textviews as the childs of the linear layout and apply a layout weight of 0,25 on every one of them. do the same for the single list row view and you will get the result that you want.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. you can use a gridview widget to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see the rest of your code but you can try and put the headers as the first row on your ListView instead of the TextViews..